# Associative array in java?

Tags: java, json

I want add duplicate keys in map,output like the one below:

```
google:Android,google:Maps,apple:iPod,apple:iPhone,apple:iOS
```

Is it possible in java or json? please help me.

Comment: You should change the subject to say MultiMap, because that's what you apparently need. [Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is simply a hash table, or a hash map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Java. Check apache's [MultiMap.](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Comment: I think apache's multihashmap is deprecated.

Comment: @user1021904 No it was just [moved to the `map` subpackage](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html).

Comment: Perhaps you should link to 4.1 Javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

I like the MultiMap answer above.  But if you want to stick to the java.util collections, try a map of lists.

Comment: please help me how to do that?

Comment: MultiMap is just a nicer API wrapper around a Map with ArrayList keys anyway.

Comment: @user1021904 - show us your attempt at using a map of lists if you want help.

Comment: To respond to "how to do that" more details are required.  Are duplicates required/not required?  Do you just want to build the map?  Do you need to remove or update keys, remove or update values in the map, and so on.  

It's not hard, but maybe using MultiMap is your best move here.

Answer (score 3):

Even better than a map of lists is a map of sets, assuming you only want to allow duplicate *keys* and not duplicate *associations*. It could be done like this:

```
import java.util.*;
Map<K, Set<V>> yourMap = new HashMap<K, Set<V>>();

public void add(K key, V value) {
    if (!yourMap.containsKey(key)) {
        yourMap.put(key, new HashSet<V>());
    }
    yourMap.get(key).add(value);
}
```

Replace `K` and `V` with the actual key and value types.

Answer (score 2):

Map in java can never has duplicate key, however you can put multiple values for a particular key:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

You can also use `MultivaluedMap`.

Comment: Kunda bora - you need to learn how to use Markdown to format your Answers properly.  Read the Help page.

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution apart from Apache's library is to use Google's guava libraries.  Guava implements a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html), and here's a blog post that explains [how to use Guava's Multimaps](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html)